# How to remove the data after user has logged out?

Tags: security, meteor, logout

I was following along the example Lending Library app in the book "Packtpub.Getting.Started.with.Meteor.js". It is running at:

http://matloob.lendlib.meteor.com

It works fine, but when a user logs out when one category is open and its items are being displayed, that category and its items remain on the page while the rest is filtered out. On refreshing the page the remaining category is also filtered out.

The publish function is:

```
Meteor.publish("Categories", function () {
    Meteor.flush(); // I added this so it will flush out the remaining data, but :(

    return lists.find({owner: this.userId}, {fields: {Category: 1}});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to point out the exact vulnerability withour seeing more code but this is what I could find out: even if not logged in as a user one can set the session variable `current_list` to an id to get the corresponding list document:

```
Session.set("current_list",'ZLREaTCPiC6E7ece3')
```

So I assume that somewhere in your code you publish the details of a list given its id.

At least this would explain why the list remains even after logging out when a category is selected (which in turn means `current_list` holds an id).

Possibly publishing the list is done using `Deps.autorun` since the list is immediately published once the session variable is changed.

Maybe you can find that piece of code and post it or just change it so that it also includes a check whether the user is the owner of that list or category.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `user-status` package to listen for users logging out and doing some cleanup on the server as a result:

> https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status

Specfically, you can use the following callback:

```
UserStatus.on "sessionLogout", (advice) ->
  console.log(advice.userId + " with session " + advice.sessionId + " logged out")
```